# Probability of a continuous r.v. at certain value

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

Pick two random variables as follows. First pick $X$ uniformly on (0,1), this gives some observed value $X = x$, then pick $Y$ uniformly on $(0, x)$. What's the probability that $X \geq 1/2$ if $Y = 1/4$?

I know $P(X \geq 1/2 | Y = 1/4) = \frac{P(X \geq 1/2)P(Y = 1/4 | X \geq 1/2)}{P(Y = 1/4)}$. Though $P(X \geq 1/2)$ can be easily obtained, since $Y$ is continuous, probability of $Y$ equal to certain point would just be zero. How to derive $P(Y = 1/4 | X \geq 1/2)$ and $P(Y = 1/4)$?

Comment: $\mathbb P(Y=1/4)$ and $\mathbb P(Y=1/4\mid X\geqslant 1/2)$ are zero because $Y$ is continuous.